# pseudocode for reading these command line arguments?

Tags: c

I wrote a program that takes in a txt file and returns an array of the number of characters, words, and lines. This is basically the `wc` command.

I'm trying to implement `-l`, `-c`, `-w` for the user to enter into the command line to specify which ones the user wants to see. If none of `-l`, `-c`, `-w` are given, it prints all of them. If the user types `./wc -l -c -w -l -c -w` then it still only prints it once. After `-l`, `-c`, `-w` the user types in the file name.

An example would be `./wc -l -c -w alice.txt anh.txt`.
This would print lines, characters, and words for both text files.

I'm struggling to think of a way to do this. Here is the code I have that returns the array.

I have an idea something like we loop through all arguments and if it finds either `-l` or `-c` or `-w` it will return 1 for true, add it to a separate array, and use that array to print out what is needed.

```
int *get_counts(char *filename)
{

        FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

        if (file == NULL)
        {
                printf("NULL FILE");
                exit(1);
        }

        int c;
        bool whitespace = true;
        static int arr[3] = {0,0,0};
        for(;;)
        {
                c = fgetc(file);
                if (c == EOF)
                {
                        break;
                }
                else if (c == '\n')
                {
                        arr[0]++;
                }
                else if (whitespace && !isspace(c))
                {
                        arr[1]++;
                        whitespace = false;
                }
                else if (!whitespace && isspace(c))
                {
                        whitespace = true;
                }
                arr[2]++;
        }
        fclose(file);
        return arr;
}
```

Comment: So your question is how you can express parsing the command-line arguments in pseudocode?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is pseudocode for parsing the arguments:

```
Initialize flag variables: l, c, w = 0
Loop from i = 1 to argc - 1:
    Check value of argv[i]:
        When "-l", set l flag to 1
        When "-c", set c flag to 1
        When "-w", set w flag to 1
        Otherwise, break loop
Interpret remaining values from argv as filenames
```

Comment: How would I throw an error if argv[i] is neither -l -c -w or valid text file names?